# Difference in T-distribution value calculated from excel and manually checked from table

Tags: excel, statistics, t-test

I want to find the value of a T-distribution for a level of significance set at 5% and degrees of freedom equaling 10 in an excel sheet. When manually calculating from a table, I found the value is 2.228, but Excel gives a value of 0.961. Am I doing something wrong here?

I used the following equation in Excel for the two-tailed test.

```
  T.DIST.2T(0.05,10) = 0.961
```

[This is the t-distribution table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59GyV.jpg)
From this table, the value for the 5% level of significance and 10 degrees of freedom is 2.228.

Answer (score 1):

The function to find critical value needs to be inverse function. If you refer to the **T.DIST.2T** [function documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/t-dist-2t-function-198e9340-e360-4230-bd21-f52f22ff5c28), you can observe that X argument is the value at which to evaluate the distribution; not level of significance.

What you need is the inverse function **T.INV.2T** [function documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/t-inv-2t-function-ce72ea19-ec6c-4be7-bed2-b9baf2264f17).

```
  T.INV.2T(0,05;10) = 2,228138852
```